# Basics in getting input data from front end with AngularJS to databse through Spring MVC

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to both AngularJS and Spring MVC. I have been able to use both of them successfully separate, but now that I need to combine them, I can't see to understand the concept.

Let's say I just want to take an input for "username", and be able to add that to a database... how would I go about that? Here are the steps I had so far:

1. Create front end with html/angularjs: play.html

   ```
   <form name="myForm" ng-submit="register()">
       Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
       <!-- Email: <input type="email" ng-model="PlayController.user.email"> -->
       <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
   </form>

   <h2>Your name: {{user.name}}</h2>
   ```
2. create the controller that handles /play: playCtrl.js

   ```
   debugger;
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

   /*
    * CONTROLLERS METHOD
    */

   myApp.controller('PlayController', function($scope, PlayerService) {

   $scope.message = "Let's play!";
   $scope.message2 = "Please enter your name";
   $scope.user = {
       name : ''/*
                    * , email: ''
                    */
   };
   $scope.register = function() {
       PlayerService.AddPlayerToDB($scope.user);
   }
   }).factory("PlayerService", [ '$http', function($http) { // Creating factory
                                                           // named
                                                           // "PlayerService
   var REQUEST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://13.59.197.145:8085/Project2/#/play'
   var playerObject = {} // create playerObject

   playerObject.AddPlayerToDB = function(user) {
       $http.post(REQUEST_SERVICE_URI, user).then(function(response) {
           alert(response.status);
       })
   }

   return playerObject;

   } ])
   ```

(I already know my problem was on the page above ^^^. Just don't understand it)

3. Create the Spring Java controller to handle the input, SpringController.java:

   ```
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
   import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

   import com.revature.bean.Users;
   import com.revature.service.Register;

   @Controller
   public class SpringController {


   @RequestMapping(value="/play",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String registerUser(Users user, BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap modelMap, HttpSession session){
   Register r = new Register();

   if(r.createUser(user.getUsername())){
   session.setAttribute("username", user.getUsername());
   session.setAttribute("role", user.getRole());
   session.setAttribute("status", user.getStatus());

   System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getUsername());

   return "lobby";


   }else{

       return "login";

   }

   }
   ```

My code never actually gets to this file ^^. I have all the dependencies set up. Any help?

Comment: Why do you have "#' in your REQUEST_SERVICE_URI?

Comment: Because that's what my url is. Its a single page application

Comment: Yes, but does it map to your Spring controller? Is your web.xml configured to handle url that starts or contains '#' in it?

Comment: I'm not aware of that. My safe guess would be no, since I was trying to make it all in a single page. Is there a way to make just that action without the # ?

Comment: Your REQUEST_SERVICE_URI should point to Spring controller and not back to your page. Make sure to get the URL to your controller right and test to see if you can do post request to it and then point REQUEST_SERVICE_URI to that url.

Comment: Hey @tsolakp so how do I point it to the Spring controller? I was under the impression I had to give it an URL

Comment: That depends how you setup your web.xml. Try 'http://13.59.197.145:8085/Project2/play' (without #).